# what is Notif-Eff feature in diameter protocol?

Tags: lte, 4g, diameter-protocol

I have recently started working on diameter protocol Sh interface.
In TS 29.328, Section 6.1.1.1, it is given as

*5. The HSS shall include the data pertinent to the requested Data Reference in the User-Data AVP and if the HSS supports the Notif-Eff feature,*

I could not understand what is Notif-Eff feature. I searched for this term in RFC 3588 and RFC 6733, but could not find any relevant info.

Can you give me some idea on what is Notif-Eff feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Notif-Eff description in 3GPP TS 29.329 V9.2.0, section 7.1 - Version Control.

Please take a look there, but here is the quote from there:

> This feature is applicable to the UDR / UDA and SNR / SNA command pairs. If
>   both the HSS and the AS support this feature and if multiple subscriptions to
>   notifications are associated with a Public User Identity, the HSS may combine
>   the notifications for multiple Data References and Service Indications into a
>   single notification message. Similarly the User Data Request / Answer will
>   allow multiple data references and Service Indications and Identity Sets. The
>   User Data Answer will be able to combine DataReference items resulting in the
>   User Data Answer contents including a single XML document with the
>   separable XML sections populated.
>   Additionally, this feature allows concurrent subscriptions to different Identity
>   Sets

Answer (score 0):

Three areas for this:

```
Notif-Eff for RepositoryData implies - RepositoryData with multiple Service-Indications in the same message.

Notif-Eff for non-Transparent Data-reference implies multiple data-reference can be queried and answered back in a single request/response by Application Server/HSS .

This also refers to having multiple Identity-Set in a single data-reference e.g. IMSPublicIdentity 

And finally merging all the notifications and send them in a single message.
```